Update godot scene rendering inside editor on property change
I have a main scene and a child scene. 
A child scene is a Node3D with MeshInstance3D + BoxMesh. 

The following script is attached to the child scene's root: 
@tool
extends Node3D

@export_group("Highlight")

@export var update = false : 
    set(value): update_inspector(value)

func update_inspector(value):
    visible = value
    visibility_changed.emit()
    notify_property_list_changed()

The property inspector of the child scene root contains Group "Highlight" + property "Update" inside. 
Pressing on that property does not affect child scene rendering inside editor at all, but checkbox changes ok. 
If I insert the child scene into main scene and press on that Update property then it works only once and checkbox does not even visually update after it worked once. The inserted child scene does not respect changing visibility inside update_inspector also. 
I do not observe any errors in the Output window.
I expect Update property to change visibility of the entire child scene both when editing the child scene itself and when using it from the main scene as if use "Eye" button. 
Godot 4.3, Ubuntu 22.04 
What am I doing wrong?

My stupidity is legendary. I should do:

@export var update = false :
set(value):
update = value
update_inspector(value)

But doing the same inside update_inspector causes infinite recursion.
